# Are APIs an intermediary of different softwares to communicate or are they the server which provides data back to another software?

Tags: api, architecture, server

The definition of an API seems very broad and I don't understand whether an API is the link that connects different software or whether the server that provides data like how a airport company provides fight information to a website is the API.

Could it be both?

Answer (score 1):

It can be both. In practical terms, the most common way two pieces of software interact with each other is through APIs. The two pieces of software might be living on the same computer (e.g. an App using services provided by the OS). They can also be running on different computers separated by internet.

APIs often consist of classes and methods/functions. For a given API method/function, in general it does one or more of these 3 things:

1. retrieve information
2. store/update information
3. perform an operation

For example, an airport company runs a server exposing REST APIs that provide flight information. A client (e.g. a smartphone app) calls that REST API to retrieve flight information.

API spec defines a contract - the exact semantics on how caller calls the API. e.g. method names, parameter types and expected values.